# Wx Dev C++ vs Graphics.h?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, bgi

I want to use mouse handling and minor graphics in c++.I have to insert a start button along with mouse handling which starts my program along with minor graphics.I am confused whether should i used graphics.h or wx dev c++?

Comment: Both alternatives sound somehow exotic to me. Why not [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)?

Comment: This question leads to opinion based answers, IMHO. That's not suitable to SO. Please, have a look onto the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @Scheff But durig my research i found i cannot use qt in windows.Can i use it in windows?

Comment: _i cannot use qt in windows_ That's nonsense. We use Qt on Windows for commercial development. Before, we used GTK+/gtkmm but we switched as the Windows support for the latter became weak. Qt is actively developed, and Windows support is really fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.I would suggest you code blocks as i found it comparatively easier than wxdevc++.Also the user interface of Code blocks is better than Wx Dev..

Comment: That's a comment not an answer. Please, delete it.